# How to mail message body text in color Blue |Linux |

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario where 
The Code works perfectly

But I want some text should appear blue color when mail is sent to my email id

My Code :

```
export _From=abc@in.co
export _To=example@gmail.com
export _Subject=Remove files 
export _cp = '/demo/f1.txt'
export _msg = 'Classified: Student'

echo -e "\n $_msg  \n\n Hi Friends, \n\n Files Removed Successfully \n\n Note:- Auto-generated mail, please do not reply to this mail." | mailx -a $_cp -vvv -s "$_Subject" -r "$_From" $_To
```

In the above code you can see the parameter called $_msg and "_msg"

This message should appear in blue color when the above code is Run and mail is sent to me

Comment: You can attempt to use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) but I am unsure that mail transport can encode the escapes (and they are terminal dependent and there is no guarantee that the mail-reader on the other end will even interpret them). E-mail should be plain-text.

Comment: A better approach is for the reader to configure their own MUA to highlight messages in a way that suits them, rather than the sender.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the below changes in your existing script to print the message in blue color.

```
echo -e '\033[01;36m' "\n $_msg  \n\n Hi Friends, \n\n Files Removed Successfully \n\n Note:- Auto-generated mail, please do not reply to this mail." | mailx -a $_cp -vvv -s "$_Subject" -r "$_From" $_To
```

Comment: Only if the reader is using the terminal type that you expect!